# Is it possible to configurate gerrit to always send the push requests to refs/for?

Tags: gerrit

my team is implementing gerrit on their git repositories.
We liked the way it works. 
As far as I understand (please, correct me if I am wrong) once gerrit is implemented it is kind of optional. If you use refs/for at the time you push, your push is sent to gerrit for review. But if you do not use refs/for it automatically pushes the code.
My question:

- Is there a way to not give the user the opportunity to push directly? I want every push to be sent to revision because sometimes the user can get to forget to add refs/for to his/her push request.

Answer (score 0):

It's optional but a person need to have a "special" permission to be able to push straight to the branch (bypassing Gerrit review). Have this permission is not the default for the most people in the most of Gerrit servers. Normally only Configuration Managers or Administrators have this permission:

```
Reference refs/heads/* Push
```

If someone who doesn't have this permission pushes straight to the branch the push will fail with "Prohibited by Gerrit" error (See [here](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/error-prohibited-by-gerrit.html) for more details).

Comment: So, if I don't have permision to push directly to the branch and I push directly to the branch, what does it happen?
What would be the difference if I push to refs/for/branch and directly to the branch if I do not have the correct permissions to push straight to the branch?